# UPDATE MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am getting an SQl syntax error when running the following query and can not see what is wrong with it:

```
$query = "UPDATE combined SET v_categories_name_1_1='Hoodie', 
v_attribute_options_id_1=1, v_attribute_values_id_1_1=1, v_attribute_values_id_1_2=2, 
v_attribute_values_id_1_3=3, v_attribute_values_id_1_4=4, 
v_attribute_values_price_1_1=0, v_attribute_values_price_1_2=0, 
v_attribute_values_price_1_3=0, v_attribute_values_price_1_4=0, 
v_attribute_options_name_1_1='Size', v_attribute_values_name_1_1_1='Small', 
v_attribute_values_name_1_2_1='Medium', v_attribute_values_name_1_3_1='Large', 
v_attribute_values_name_1_4_1='Extra Large') " .
"WHERE v_products_model='$fileName'";
```

And here is the error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE v_products_model=hs_3stm_giantsk.jpg' at line 1

UPDATE:

Thanks everyone for the super fast replies, it's solved my problem though unfortunately I can't accept them for another 9 minutes!

Comment: If you find any of the answers helpful, please accept it as the correct answer so this question can be marked as resolved. If you still have issues with it, I would love to assist. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try formatting your queries; problems become much more apparent:

```
$query = "
    UPDATE combined SET 
        v_categories_name_1_1='Hoodie', 
        v_attribute_options_id_1=1,
        v_attribute_values_id_1_1=1,
        v_attribute_values_id_1_2=2, 
        v_attribute_values_id_1_3=3, 
        v_attribute_values_id_1_4=4, 
        v_attribute_values_price_1_1=0, 
        v_attribute_values_price_1_2=0, 
        v_attribute_values_price_1_3=0,
        v_attribute_values_price_1_4=0, 
        v_attribute_options_name_1_1='Size',
        v_attribute_values_name_1_1_1='Small', 
        v_attribute_values_name_1_2_1='Medium', 
        v_attribute_values_name_1_3_1='Large', 
        v_attribute_values_name_1_4_1='Extra Large')
    WHERE v_products_model='$fileName'
";
```

That bad paren is much easier to notice when you're not just looking at one big blob of text. You would (hopefully) never write PHP like that, so why write your SQL like that?

Answer (score 2):

You close parens that you you never open.

Answer (score 2):

You have an odd `)` at the end of the line before the last.

Answer (score 2):

There is a symbol `)` appearing for no reason :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$query = "UPDATE combined SET v_categories_name_1_1='Hoodie', 
v_attribute_options_id_1=1, v_attribute_values_id_1_1=1, v_attribute_values_id_1_2=2, 
v_attribute_values_id_1_3=3, v_attribute_values_id_1_4=4, 
v_attribute_values_price_1_1=0, v_attribute_values_price_1_2=0, 
v_attribute_values_price_1_3=0, v_attribute_values_price_1_4=0, 
v_attribute_options_name_1_1='Size', v_attribute_values_name_1_1_1='Small', 
v_attribute_values_name_1_2_1='Medium', v_attribute_values_name_1_3_1='Large', 
v_attribute_values_name_1_4_1='Extra Large' " .
"WHERE v_products_model='$fileName'";
```

I removed the bracket before `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Enclosing bracket with no opening one here

```
='Extra Large')
```